# I have a android Webview I implemented but an unable to upload profile picture through the code

Tags: android, webview

I have implemented an android Webview but am unable to upload profile picture through it, tired checking different question but there is none that support my method of implementation of the webview. would appreciate a workable sample to my below code

```
public class CheckUserStatusWebView extends Fragment {
private WebView webView;

private SharedPreferences preference;
private String NAME;
private String PICTUREID;
private String userStatus;
private Toolbar toolbar;
private ProgressDialog dialog;


@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup 
container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.chec_user_status, container, false);
    webView = view.findViewById(R.id.webView);
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    preference = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("CEPF", MODE_PRIVATE);
    String webUrl = "https://xxxxxxxxxxxx=" + 
    preference.getString("USERID", null) + "&ev=20";
    Log.d("webUrl ", webUrl);

    webView.loadUrl(webUrl);
    return view;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

add this

```
web = view.findViewById(R.id.webView);
web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
web.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
web.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
String webUrl = "https://xxxxxxxxxxxx=" + 
web.loadUrl(webUrl);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Advanced Web View](https://github.com/delight-im/Android-AdvancedWebView). Using this you can get rid from upload problem.

```
<im.delight.android.webview.AdvancedWebView
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

instead of your `WebView`

Please see documentation for details

Comment: please can you kindly provide you answer using my code above